# How to put this function in timeout jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

masonry.desandro and isotope don't work when I load a file.php with ajax.
Maybe a timeout will solve the problem.

```
$(function(){

      var $container = $('#container');

      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.isotope({
          itemSelector : '.photo'
        });
      });


    });
```

Comment: Yea, maybe, who knows if you don't try.

Comment: <0_o> Meanwhile in stackoverflow !!

Comment: I'd say a timeout might solve it then...?

Comment: @Jon Someone did this and was ok (is a post on stackoverflow). I want to see if works.

Comment: So then put it in and test it out...

Comment: @Jon I dont know how. setTimeout(function(),3000);?

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some plugins may not support dynamically added elements. As a workaround you could use `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) to initialize the plugin on `focusin` the document or the parent container like :

```
$(function () {
    var $container = $('#container');
    $(document).on("focusin", function () {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.photo'
        });
    });
});
```

... or if `$container` has a parent container, apply `.on()` to such parent instead of `document` to delegate the event.

Comment: @HoaHooksonair : the structure looks OK (just remove the preceding `$` from `function` after `.click`) but I am not sure if this is the functionality you want

Comment: On click works. Now i need to find a way to load the 'plugin' after ajax loads the php file. $('#buttonRecommended').click(function(){ 




  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');
  
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.box'
      });
    });
  
  });
  });

Comment: I want when scroll end in "mydiv" to execute next code, but to remove the "scrollLoad" from the code : $( '#containter' ).scrollLoad({
   

    url : 'load_more_categ.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : '',
   
 
    start : function() {
     $('<div class="loading"><img src="bigLoader.gif"/></div>').appendTo(this);

    },
 
    ScrollAfterHeight : 95,   
 
onload : function( data ) {
$(this).append( data );
$('.loading').remove();
}, // this event fires on ajax success continueWhile : function( resp ) {
     if( $(this).children('li').length >= 100 ) {return false;}return true; }});